# Scroll down event to show appbar based on category - Flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollbar, appbar

I have an AppBar and other things in my layout. When user scrolls down, I want AppBar(actually, the Toolbar to show based on category).

How to achieve this appbar  appear when scrolling the listview ?

Here the example i want to make like this.

Before scrolling

[image]

After Scrolling Appbar Appear and fixed at top

[image]